# NET MAUI: Why "Application Version" can only be single digit integer?

Tags: maui

When publishing an MAUI app with Visual Studio, why does the "Application Version" must be a "single digit integer"? It doesn't seem feasible, because then one app can only have a maximum 9 versions.

Is this somehow correlated to the Display Version? It doesn't seem so, because I tried to upload to Google Play Store an app that had the Display Version 1.1.2, after I already had a test version with Display Version 1.1.1, but it didn't let me. As soon as I increased the "Application Version" to other number than 1, it worked.

[image]

Comment: As far as I know, the version here is the version of your Assembly i.e. the Assembly version for your .NET MAUI project and for your build number you need to set it natively